# How to run CPLEX solve on the same model with the same data multiple time?

Tags: cplex, solver, opl

I am using CPLEX (OPL) to solve my linear program, now I want to find the average running time, therefore I need to solve the same model with the same data 10 times and calculate the average. How can I do that automatically?

following is what i tested:

```
main {
var RT=0;
     for( var i=0;i<10;i++){
                        thisOplModel.generate();
                        cplex.solve();
                        RT=RT+cplex.getSolvedTime();
                        writeln("RT: "+ cplex.getSolvedTime());
                        RT=RT+cplex.getSolvedTime();
                    }
     RT=RT/10;
     writeln("avg RT: "+ RT);

}
```

this code solve the model only one time, i didn't why.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosimulation.mod)

```
int nbKids=300;

{int} nbKidsOptions={nbKids+i*10 | i in -10..2};
int x2[i in 1..card(nbKidsOptions)]=item(nbKidsOptions,i-1);
int y2[i in 1..card(nbKidsOptions)];

float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40);
writeln("nbBus30 = ",nbBus30);
}

main
{
thisOplModel.generate();
var k=1;
for(var nbKids in thisOplModel.nbKidsOptions)

{
writeln("if we need to bring ",nbKids," kids  to the zoo");
    
thisOplModel.ctKids.LB=nbKids;

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();
writeln("And the cost is ",cplex.getObjValue());
thisOplModel.y2[k]=cplex.getObjValue();
k++;
writeln();
}
}
```